# php can run the python programm from php shell but not on the webbrowser(ubuntu)

Tags: php, python, matplotlib, ipython

I have a python script that uses ipyhon and it can be executed when I run it from the terminal using php -a (interactive shell), but when I type localserver/test.php (test.php is the script wrtten with gedit in ubuntu) nothing happens and I only see a blank page. Any idea why?

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/administrator/Desktop/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Just an update: I checked the log file and it gives me a list of errors for example about the pyplot:  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2460,ax = gca() in plot

But again as I said before the python program works fine and can be executed with php if I run it from the php shell. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Did you watch logs for some info?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? How can I do that?

Comment: Log files reside in `/var/log/`, specifically the `apache2/error.log` and `php5-fpm.log`

Comment: Thanks, I think that would help.

Comment: Just an update: I checked the log file and it gives me a list of errors for example about the pyplot: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2460,ax = gca() in plot

But again as I said before the python program works fine and can be executed with php if I run it from the php shell. I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux user used to run PHP web server and PHP cli are probably different. Try to change the permissions of .py. If you can execute after that, you got your answer.

```
chmod 0777 /home/administrator/Desktop/test.py
```

Comment: That would dis-activate the test file as being executable. I did it and could not even run if from the terminal saying I do not have permission.